# Is it possible to reload delete/reload a Bigquery table whenever a specific pub/sub message is sent?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We're sending messages for multiple pub/sub tables to the same subscription. A pub/sub attribute defines which tables it writes to. Some tables are aggregate tables, that would benefit from just truncate/reloading the table.

When I try to set write disposition to truncate I get an error message

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE is not supported for an unbounded PCollection.
```

Is there any way to destroy/reload BigQuery tables when certain messages come in from pub/sub?

Comment: It seems unlikely. Apache beam does not guaranty reception order of messages. So how would you know _exactly when_ to do this ? What if the delete and populate messages come at the same time, which one to process first ?

Comment: I would get a pub/sub message with a specific attribute that says which table to populate. Based on the specific table name I would truncate the table OR append. Records would come in mini batches as line delimited lists of records within the pub/sub message. Aggregate tables should be replaced instead of appended.

Comment: The, so cause of your problem is an unbound collection. Have you tried to use a window before inserting to BigQuery ?

Comment: There's a window followed by a few transformations, but it's  throwing the above error. I think write truncate would consider the PCollection complete and that pipeline finished, where as I would want to run this indefinitely, and truncate every time a get a message with a certain attribute. Probably its not possible.